# scp a folder to my ubuntu server

Tags: ssh, file-transfer, scp

I have a folder on my mac that I need to move over to my server. I can ssh in the server but how do i get this folder up....

say I am on my local computer and the folder is named shared and I want to put it on the server in /srv/www/somesite/current. How do i enter the password in my scp command

I found this but i dont think its right

```
scp -r shared/* matt@174.143.150.55:/srv/www/somesite/current/shared
```

Comment: I might suggest using sftp instead of scp. At least for me it's more intuitive.

Answer (score 8):

```
scp -r shared matt@174.143.150.55:/srv/www/somesite/current
```

will create a folder named 'shared' in somesite/current containing all of the content.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the wildcard:

```
scp -r shared matt@174.143.150.55:/srv/www/somesite/current/
```

Assuming your server is using password auth and the standard SSH port, you should be prompted for a password.

Comment: You can also use rsync: rsync -aPzv shared matt@174.143.150.55:/srv/www/somesite/current/